# Problem with OpenCV camera based samples

Tags: windows-7, opencv

I'm doing a project on Hand Gesture Recognition , I installed OpenCV on my system it works fine except for **sample programs** related to **camera** like **bgfg_segm, camshiftdemo** etc . When I run these programs I get a window asking me to select the **Video Source** type from Integrated camera or FA VirtualCam(Fast Acces Software for Facial Recognition,Dell) . When I select Integrated cam light does not even glow whereas when I choose FA VirtualCam Cam switches on but it does not capture any image its just dark. 
    Using same setup I installed in my friend's laptop -Lenovo/WinXP it worked.

My camera works fine otherwise, no problem with it. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and all possible combination but it didn't work.

---

Configuration: Dell Studio 1558
               Ram: 4GB, 
               OS: Windows 7 Home Premium x64
               OpenCV version 2.2
               Software for camera: Dell  WebCam Central.

Answer (score 1):

There's an workaround for that, it worked for me.

You just have to capture the webcam using Processing and redirect it to OpenCV.
I explain it with more details [at the Processing forum](https://forum.processing.org/topic/solved-windows-opencv-webcam).

My source code is available [at my page](http://w3.impa.br/~tknop/tmp/blobs_win7.zip) .

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your camera is not compatible with OpenCV, see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS

I have the exact same issue on a Vaio laptop using OpenCV (light comes on but a blank image). I managed to use processing/jmyron to get the functionality I needed (face detection).

Comment: Creative Live!camera is listed as compatible but its tested in WinXP.